# Swift - Use both UIAlertController & UIAlertView for iOS 7 / iOS 8 and above

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

My app's deployment target is 7.0 . I want to use both UIAlertController and UIAlertView. I read somewhere that checking for iOS versions is not good, so i used this code :

```
if (NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") != nil) {
// UIAlertController
} else {    
// UIAlertView
```

But even if do that, i still get that "correctable" error "UIAlertController is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer" and i have to choose between 3 'Fix-it' options :

- Add 'if #available' version check ( if #available(iOS 8.0, *) { ... } else { ... })
- Add @available attribute to enclosing instance method
- Add @available attribute to enclosing class

What should i do ? Currently using Xcode 7 GM

Comment: `if #available` is the best option if you want to support both iOS versions at the same time.

Comment: If you are getting messages about `UIAlertView` being deprecated then your deployment target is not iOS 7. Check the deployment target for both the project and your target.

Comment: @rmaddy no " UIAlertView deprecated " errors, my target deployment is already set to 7.0

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the best way to do this is using the `#available` function. I've attached a code example for you.

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {

    } else {

    }
```

`#available` is the best way to do these checks.